# Failed to call AJAX confirm function and insert text value and image into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to the AJAX and PHP. I'm currently facing a problem with calling an jQuery confirm box function and insert the data into the database. When i clicked submit button, the ajax should called the confirm box function in jquery then when user clicked "YES" only the data will be inserted into the database. (The data contain of text filed and image file upload). But when i clicked the submit button, it straight away lead me to the bannerItem.php which is wrong.

Here is the AJAX code that i use to call the confirm box function and run the php code:

```
//File and text upload with formDATA function
                $("form#form").confirm(function(){
                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                confirm: function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'bannerItem.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        async: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if(!alert('Banner Had Successfully Updated.')){location.reload();}
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    });

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Here is the bannerItem.php code:

```
<?php
include 'dbConnection.php';

global $dbLink;


    $target_file = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    //Check image file type




            //Gather all required data
            $item_id = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['banner_id']);
            $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_POST['bannerName']);
            $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));


            if(!isset($mydata) || $mystring == null){
                //Create the SQL query
                $query = "UPDATE banner_item SET banner_name='$name', banner_created=NOW() WHERE banner_item_id = '$item_id' ";
                //$query = "INSERT INTO banner_item (banner_item_id, banner_name,banner_data,banner_created) VALUES ('{$item_id}','{$name}','{$data}', NOW())";

            }
            else if($name==''){
                //Create the SQL query
                $query = "UPDATE banner_item SET banner_data='$data', banner_created=NOW() WHERE banner_item_id = '$item_id' ";
                //$query = "INSERT INTO banner_item (banner_item_id, banner_name,banner_data,banner_created) VALUES ('{$item_id}','{$name}','{$data}', NOW())";

            }
            else{
                //Create the SQL query
                $query = "UPDATE banner_item SET banner_name='$name', banner_data='$data', banner_created=NOW() WHERE banner_item_id = '$item_id' ";
                //$query = "INSERT INTO banner_item (banner_item_id, banner_name,banner_data,banner_created) VALUES ('{$item_id}','{$name}','{$data}', NOW())";

            }

    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();

?>
```

Here is the code that i used to submit the form:

```
<!--Banner Item No 1 Start-->
                    <div class="box box-primary1"  id="no1" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Edit Banner Image No.1 <small>编辑器</small></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                        <form id="form" action="bannerItem.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <input type="hidden" name="banner_id" value="1"></input>
                                <div class="form-group" >
                                    <label for="bannerName">Banner Name 旗帜名称</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bannerName" id="bannerName" placeholder="Please Enter Name" onChange="checkDisabled(testing);">
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                                    <input type="file" id="uploaded_file" name="uploaded_file"  onChange="checkDisabled(testing);"><br>
                                    <p class="help-block">Your picture size not more than 2MB.  (Only JPEG/JPG/PNG is allowed)</p>
                                </div>  

                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <button id="testing" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Update</button>      
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->


                        </form>                  <!-- Date range -->
                            <!-- /.form group -->

                            <!-- Date and time range -->




                            <!-- /.form group -->

                            <!-- Date and time range -->
                            <!-- /.form group -->

                        </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div><!-- /.box -->
                    <!--Banner Item No 1 End-->
```

I'm not sure which part i did wrong on the ajax code. Please point out my mistake so that i can change, Thanks and good day ahead :)

Comment: Whats the bannerItem.php coding?

Comment: hi there please refer the above php code i had just paste it in. But i think my php code should't be the problem, i think my AJAX code should be somethingwrong

Comment: Hi @NewToJS, my ajax did not alert me anything, when i press submit button nothing happen which is weird.

Comment: @NewToJS Hi, i had try replace with console.log(data), but when i clicked the submit button, still nothing happen

Comment: @NewToJS

i get this following message on the console:

Empty string passed to getElementById(). foundation.min.js:18
GET http://localhost/cms/img/avatar3.png [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 14ms]
ReferenceError: dataOptions is not defined jquery.confirm.js:147
SyntaxError: function statement requires a name banner.php:826
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.